# TextBoxFor on a boolean field renders the same value even if it was modified on controller side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a simple form with a textbox (and a model editor I want to render in specific cases)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Flow"))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IsConfirmed)

    @if (Model.IsConfirmed)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Preview)
    }
}
```

The model used in this view is the following

```
public class ImportViewModel
{
    public Boolean IsConfirmed { get; set; }

    public PreviewViewModel Preview { get; set; }

    public ImportViewModel()
    {
        this.IsConfirmed = false;
    }
}
```

The form posts on the following controller

```
public class FlowController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import(ImportViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (model.IsConfirmed)
                {
                    // do something else
                }
                else
                {
                    model.Preview = Preview(model.strCA, model.SelectedAccount);
                    model.IsConfirmed = true;

                    return View(model);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("arf", ex);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

On first load, the textbox contains "false"

When posted, the property IsConfirmed of the model is set to "true" and this model is passed to the same view.

I expect the textbox to be "true" but it is still "false"... moreover the Preview property is correctly rendered, so it means Model.IsConfirmed is indeed true...

Am I missing something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you remove the value from the ModelState if you intend to modify it:

```
ModelState.Remove("IsConfirmed");
model.IsConfirmed = true;
```

The reason you need to do that is because, by design, all Html helpers (such as `TextBoxFor`) will first look for a value in the ModelState when binding and only not found they will use the value on your model. And since there's a value with the same name in the ModelState (coming from the POST request), that's what's being used.

Comment: That was it... I find this quite confusing if you don't know where to look at... Thanks anyway :)